Add image as icon for window
this is the code
import javax.swing.*;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Starting up...");
        createWindow();
    }
    private static void createWindow() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple GUI");
        
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
      //Ask for window decorations provided by the look and feel.
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        //Set the frame icon to an image loaded from a file.
        frame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("/Users/orlygurhugason/Örminal/Orminal/src/Public/Backdrop.png").getImage());
        frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/Users/orlygurhugason/Örminal/Orminal/src/Public/Backdrop.png")));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true); //Basic setup
    }
}

the out put is this:

i mostly looked around the internet

Better to load your files/images as resources:
Netbeans
Eclipse


An Icon can be shared by multiple components, to there is no need to read the Icon twice. 2) Not sure what the image shows us. Your image is the entire desktop. I would expect to see an image of the frame with the icon set in the top left and as label in the frame.


I think they’re trying to set the application icon, which is different than the frame icon. I’m not sure if the frame icon is used in macOS.

one of the images is the backround the other is the icon that i have problems and thank you for youre help
